# VSCODE crashing when running debugger

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

Whenever I run my file (testy.py) in the VSCode debugger, it crashes out after running/trying to run "from skimage import io". It will just print the first "hi" and then the debugger will stop running after that. However, when I run the code without the debugger it works just fine. I've tried adding the justMyCode:false configuration to the json file and it still doesn't work in the debugger. I'm very confused please help!
Here is the code I currently have:

```
print("hi") #for debugging purposes
from skimage import io
print("hi") #for debugging purposes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
print("hi") #for debugging purposes
origImage = io.imread('vogue-color.png')
(height, width, channels) = origImage.shape
startCropX = width % 2
startCropY = height % 2
croppedImage = origImage[startCropY:, startCropX:]
plt.imshow(croppedImage)
plt.show()
```

I've tried adding the justMyCode:false configuration to the json file and it still doesn't work in the debugger. I added print statements to see where the debugger stops running and it stops at the second line.

Comment: I would suggest providing a view into the debugger output. From your code alone we cannot determine what is going on with your VSCode environment, as you have stated the code works fine without debugging on. So check that you do not have breakpoints enabled (which will halt execution at places you've selected in the IDE).

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Also include Python version, VS Code Python extension version, and debugpy extension version.

Comment: Do you have skimage installed in your python environment? Can you run the code directly with success? Is your extension version up to date?